# keep executing a function when mouse down

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var money = 10
var generators = []
var lastUpdate = Date.now()


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
  let generator = {
    cost:Math.pow(Math.pow(10,i),i)*10,
    bought:0,
    amount:0,
    mult:1
  }
  generators.push(generator)
}



function format (amount){
    let power = Math.floor(Math.log10(amount))
    let mantissa = amount / Math.pow(10 , power)
    if (power < 3) { return amount.toFixed(2)}
    return mantissa.toFixed(2) + "e" + power
}




function buyGenerator(i){

  let g = generators[i - 1]
  if(g.cost > money) return
  money -= g.cost 
  g.amount += 1
  g.bought += 1
  g.mult *= 1.05
  g.cost *= 1.6
}

function updateGUi (){
  document.querySelector("#currency").textContent = "you have $" + format(money)
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    let g = generators [i]
    document.getElementById("gen"+ (i+1)).innerHTML = "Amount: " + format(g.amount) + "<br> Bought: " + g.bought + "<br> Multiplier: " + format(g.mult) +"X <br> Cost: " + format(g.cost)
    if(g.cost > money) document.getElementById("gen"+[i+1]).classList.add("locked")
    else document.getElementById("gen"+[i+1]).classList.remove("locked")
  }
}

function productloop (diff){
  money += generators[0].amount * generators[0].mult * diff
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++ ){
    generators[i - 1].amount += generators[i].amount * generators[i].mult * diff / 5
  }
}

function mainloop (){
  var diff = (Date.now() - lastUpdate)/1000
  productloop(diff)
  updateGUi()
  lastUpdate = Date.now()

}

setInterval(mainloop, 50) 

updateGUi()
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.generator {
   border: 2px solid black;
   background-color: rgb(134, 230, 134);
   text-align: center;
   width: 300px;
   padding: 15px;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;

}

.generators-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
}

#currency {
    margin: 40px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;

}

.locked {
    background-color:rgb(221, 63, 63);
}

@media (max-width : 7in){
    .generators-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .generator {
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: rgb(134, 230, 134);
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
     
     }

     .locked {
        background-color:rgb(221, 63, 63);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="currency"> you have 0$</div>
   <div class="generators-container">
     <div class="generator" id="gen1" onmousedown="buyGenerator(1)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen2" onmousedown="buyGenerator(2)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen3" onmousedown="buyGenerator(3)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen4" onmousedown="buyGenerator(4)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen5" onmousedown="buyGenerator(5)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen6" onmousedown="buyGenerator(6)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen7" onmousedown="buyGenerator(7)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen8" onmousedown="buyGenerator(8)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen9" onmousedown="buyGenerator(9)"></div>
     <div class="generator" id="gen10" onmousedown="buyGenerator(10)"></div>
   </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can I keep executing the function buyGenerator when I hold click and I have the money to do so?
it should work on phones to
normally I save it to local storage but on here I kept getting errors for that for some reason
everything works it would just be way nicer if I could just hold my click to buy a lot of upgrades instead of clicking continuously

it's for an incremental game I'm building

Comment: It would be super cool if your runnable snippet had things I could click.

Comment: Also `generators` is undefined

Comment: You could onmousedown kick off a fast setinterval and then onmouseup cancel it.

Comment: You should probably implement a proper main game loop. This is done using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). The loop function you pass will be called about 60 times per second on desktops. Next you need a state variable that gets set when the mouse is held down and reset in `onmouseleave` or `onmouseup`. Inside your loop function, you check the state var and act accordingly.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/87m13tdL/

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247497/how-to-detect-if-mouse-button-is-held-down-for-a-certain-amount-of-time-after-cl

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is using an interval or timeout. Mousedown, start the timer. Listen for a mouseup and cancel it.

```js
const generators = [
  { cost: 100, amount: 0, bought: 0, mult: 1, cost: 1 },
  { cost: 200, amount: 0, bought: 0, mult: 1, cost: 1 },
  { cost: 300, amount: 0, bought: 0, mult: 1, cost: 1 }
];
let money = 100000;

function buyGenerator(i) {
  let g = generators[i]
  if (g.cost > money) return
  money -= g.cost
  g.amount += 1
  g.bought += 1
  g.mult *= 1.05
  g.cost *= 1.6
  console.log(money);
}

let activeTimer = null;
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
  const gen = evt.target.closest('[data-generator]');
  if (gen) {
    const genId = gen.dataset.generator;
    activeTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
      buyGenerator(genId);
    }, 300);
  }
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  if (activeTimer) {
    window.clearTimeout(activeTimer);
    activeTimer = null;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="generator" data-generator="0">Gen 1</div>
  <div class="generator" data-generator="1">Gen 2</div>
  <div class="generator" data-generator="2">Gen 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something using setInterval that could be useful for your case:
Basicaly i'm just using the setInterval as a loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mousedown = false;
    var counters  = {1:1,2:1};
    var loop;
    var selected = 1;
    function  btnDown(a){
        selected = a;
        mousedown=true;
        loop = setInterval(()=>{
                counters[selected]+=1;
                document.getElementById("btn"+selected).innerHTML = counters[selected];
            },100);
    }
    function btnUp(){
        mousedown = false;
        clearInterval(loop);
}

</script>

<button type="button" id="btn1" onmousedown="btnDown(1)" onmouseup="btnUp(1)">a</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2" onmousedown="btnDown(2)" onmouseup="btnUp(2)">a</button>
```

I hope it helped ^^
edit : couldn't manage to give parameters to callback function so i made a "selected" var