# mouseHold and mouseDown - different functionalities

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am trying to have a functionality (1) if mouseDown has been pressed for more than x amount of time. If it has been briefly pressed (less than x amount of time) i want to have another functionality (2) happen.

```
function onMouseDown(event) { 
  var delay;
   timeClickDown = Date.now(); 
  delay= timeClickDown-timeClickUp;
   if(delay>x) {functionality(1)}
else if(delay<=x) {functionality(2)}}

 function onMouseUp(event){
   timeClickUp = Date.now();
 }
```

Doing this right now works but only after i click twice (because timeClickDown gets its value only after first click).

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30249552/4157513

Comment: @wahoowa Thank you for responding but i don't find that one can help me (maybe i don't understand it). I have the mouseDown function which has a functionality inside it (it moves a camera for a 3D scene). The problem is, i want the camera to move only if the mouseDown has been held for x amount of miliseconds. If mouseDown is held for more than x miliseconds i want to return.